# Enforce "this" access

Tags: java

Due to some weird requirements (post processing of source code) I need to use "this." syntax instead of just the member variable name. Is there a way I can enforce static checks at compile time to ensure that I am using "this." instead of the shorter equivalent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Eclipse you could go into Java / Compiler / Errors and warnings / Code Style and change "unqualified access to instance field" to Error instead of the default Ignore.

EDIT: Using a mixture of this change to the IDE (if you're using Eclipse, of course) and checkstyle as part of your build rules should suffice.

Answer (score 9):

Have you ever used [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)? You can define your code style rule in xml and run it at compile time. There is also a maven plugin if you care.

Comment: In particular, look at "RequireThis" in http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html.

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse offers the ability to configure the Clean Up tool to do this for you.[image]

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ has a code style check for `Instance field access not qualified with 'this'`

It also has the option correct this for a field, class or modules.  This sort of thing could safe you having to touch many files yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use checkstyle to impose such requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a static code analyzer like CheckStyle to acomplish this in compile time.

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RequireThis